# Apache .htaccess rule to hide folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In .htaccess I'd like to have a rule to find out if a request is to a folder, before Apache redirects to the folder. If it is a forbidden folder, it should display my custom 404 page.

How can I do it?

Here is my attempt, where I want all sub-directories of the "test" folder to be invisible to the user, i.e. http://www.example.com/test/subfolder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/.+
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ 404.php  [L]
```

Comment: You will probably have to turn off [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash), because I am pretty sure mod_dir does its work before it even gets to mod_rewrite's stuff.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it seems to work and jet I haven't found any security issues. All my 30+ unit tests passed! Great! Post it as an answer and I accept it.